# Multiplatform programming - MacOS and Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, macos, cross-platform, system-calls

I am writing program in C language. At this moment I have this program and libraries done and running on macOS Sierra. Now I want to port this code to also work on Windows 10.

The program specific features:

- it is a library rather than an actual program with a GUI
- GUI will be added to current version in the future, and here, can I do it on macOS in Cocoa and on Windows in C# or make it as web application? Don't consider exactly how I will do it, but I don't want to limit different options in the future
- My current macOS/unix version uses **-std=c99** C language, I have **make** files to build static libraries with extension **.a** and **test programs**. I also have **CMake** as alternative for compilation for libraries and test programs
- In the program I am using libraries such as **POSIX threads**, **semaphores, TCP networking sockets**
- I also have a library that I think is **OS X specific** and it uses **Carbon?** i.e. system calls from apple written in C that controls keyboard/mouse input and some macOS system features
- In windows, with this project I am planning to add similar keyboard/mouse input features and other windows-specific system calls (I think it will be **Windows API (Win32)** code. It will be code specific for Windows OS

Now I have many doubts on how I should port the Windows version and develop both macOS and Windows version of the application simultaneously.

1. Should I use something like Cygwin and try to stick to POSIX or rewrite my code to using windows API Threads? and WinSock? Doesn't Cygwin usage disable usage of Win32 API for implementing windows specific handling of keyboard/mouse inputs and other widows specific code.
2. How should I organize my code? I was thinking about something like **Common** source code libraries, **OS_X directory** with macOS specific source code and libraries, **Windows directory** with Windows specific source code and libraries.
3. How should I compile i.e. write Cmake, Makefile scripts do some conditional linking? Or write separate scripts for macOS and Windows source code?
4. Should I write Windows specific code, OS X specific code in separate files and conditionally include them in other source code? Or in the one source code file include "both OS-sepcific code" using some conditional C macros?
5. Could you recommend some tutorials or guides addressing this problem, writing C libraries, programs that have some source code common on OS X and Windows, and some code specific to OS X and Windows operating systems and that  indicate how to solve such program organization in the best way (best practices).
6. Maybe I just should write 2 separate programs (2 projects copies) one for macOS and the other for Windows, and just copy and paste what is common in realised features but programmed with POSIX, networking system-specific libraries. How to maintain such duplicating code properly?

Comment: I doubt this will get a decent answer on SO, it's not really the right site for this sort of question. You might want to [hire a tutor](https://www.codementor.io/tutors).

Comment: Hm, yes the problem is complex, i am looking for some big picture and best practices. I could go different ways and try myself what works and what not but it will take huge amount of time. It doesn't have to be simple answer it can be some link to good tutorial, article about this issue, maybe book. I am writing my app in IntelliJ CLion an would like to stick to it on both system. I think that very helpful will be also source codes of projects on github that are not too large, and yet shows how to solve this issue. So i could anlyze code organization. I try too look into opencv source code

Comment: I would definitively give [Qt](https://www.qt.io) a try. [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html) has become a very mature UI framework and [Qt](https://www.qt.io)'s core is great for developing multiplatform applications and/or libraries using one codebase